# Using NSIS command line to globally define product definitions

Tags: command-line-arguments, nsis

I'd like to control the branding for my NSIS installer by passing a parameter to makensis:

```
makensis.exe /DCOMPANY_X=1 installer.nsi
```

The following are the first few lines listed in my NSI file:

```
!ifdef ${COMPANY_X}
  !define PRODUCT_NAME "Widget Pro"
  !define PRODUCT_VERSION "v2.0"
  !define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "ACE Company"
  !define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "www.ace.com"
  !define PRODUCT_COPYRIGHT "Copyright 2013 Ace"
!else
  !define PRODUCT_NAME "Widget Maker"
  !define PRODUCT_VERSION "v12.3"
  !define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "ACME CO"
  !define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "www.acme.com"
  !define PRODUCT_COPYRIGHT "Copyright 2013 ACME"
!endif
```

I use these defines throughout my script.

The problem I'm encountering is that even with COMPANY_X defined on the command line, execution is passing through to the second block of defines (ACME).

Being new to NSIS, I'm sure there's a better way to handle this. I'd also like to use a switch statement to define multiple companies. If I do this, the compiler warns me that I need to place this code in a section or function.

One thing that might complicate a solution for this is that I'm signing my uinstaller with a two pass process:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Signing_an_Uninstaller

Kudos to the NSIS team and all the contributors. No way I'd ever go back to InstallShield.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!ifdef ${COMPANY_X}` is actually going to check if `1` is defined!

The syntax is !ifdef name_of_define: `!ifdef COMPANY_X`

...or if the content of the define matters: `!if ${COMPANY_X} = 1`

Comment: Any idea on how I can define more than 2 companies with a switch, yet still have them as globals at the top of my NSI? If I embed ifdef statements inside the else, I get multiple 'PRODUCT_NAME doesn't exist' errors.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean but I'm sure you can come up with something. Take a look at http://pastebin.com/xJNHwRbb

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was able to do what I wanted using !ifndef. The code is a little ugly, but it works. Cool stuff!